# Change the multi-label X-axis label in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

i have this code

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggprism)

MLE <- c(0.01866, 0.015364, 0.015821, 0.008736, 0.008433,   0.008655,   0.003426,   0.003403,   0.00352)
KS <- c(0.021095,   0.016748,   0.017564,   0.010222,   0.009470,   0.009559,   0.003929,   0.003907,   0.00396)
AD <- c(0.020344,   0.016381,   0.016299,   0.009494,   0.008962,   0.009009,   0.003645,   0.003625,   0.003698)
CS <- c(0.021689,   0.017805,   0.017741,   0.010436,   0.009783,   0.00986,    0.004007,   0.004073,   0.00404)

df <- structure(list(A = c(50, 50, 50, 100, 100, 100, 250, 250, 250),
                     R = c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R1", "R2", "R3", "R1", "R2", "R3"), 
                     MLE = MLE, 
                     KS = KS, 
                     AD = AD, 
                     CS = CS, 
                     `round(2)` = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(MLE:CS) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), as.factor)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = R, y = value, group=name, col=name)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1.2) +
  geom_point(size=2.5) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Mean Square Errors") +
  scale_color_grey() + 
  theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(~A, nrow=1, strip.position="bottom")
```

which draws a graph like this
[image: Initial Graph]

I would like to do several things:

1- change the numbers in the rectangles (i.e. 50, 100, and 250) to m=50, m=100, and m=250, respectively

2- Make the R1, R2, and R3 bolded for all of them

Regarding the first one my attempt is this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggprism)

MLE <- c(0.01866, 0.015364, 0.015821, 0.008736, 0.008433,   0.008655,   0.003426,   0.003403,   0.00352)
KS <- c(0.021095,   0.016748,   0.017564,   0.010222,   0.009470,   0.009559,   0.003929,   0.003907,   0.00396)
AD <- c(0.020344,   0.016381,   0.016299,   0.009494,   0.008962,   0.009009,   0.003645,   0.003625,   0.003698)
CS <- c(0.021689,   0.017805,   0.017741,   0.010436,   0.009783,   0.00986,    0.004007,   0.004073,   0.00404)

df <- structure(list(A = c(paste("m", 50, sep = "="), paste("m", 50, sep = "="), paste("m", 50, sep = "="), 
                           paste("m", 100, sep = "="), paste("m", 100, sep = "="), paste("m", 100, sep = "="), 
                           paste("m", 250, sep = "="), paste("m", 250, sep = "="), paste("m", 250, sep = "=")),
                     R = c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R1", "R2", "R3", "R1", "R2", "R3"), 
                     MLE = MLE, 
                     KS = KS, 
                     AD = AD, 
                     CS = CS, 
                     `round(2)` = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(MLE:CS) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), as.factor)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = R, y = value, group=name, col=name)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1.2) +
  geom_point(size=2.5) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Mean Square Errors") +
  scale_color_grey() + 
  theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(~A, nrow=1, strip.position="bottom")
```

And the result is
[image: Wrong graph]

The issue is that the order is messed up now even though the data points themselves are still correct, I tried rearranging the values in the data frame but to no avail.

Regarding the second issue, I don't even know where to start. So any help regarding the bolding would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the facets in the correct order, you need to have the levels of the factor variables in the desired order. In your case, the correct order would just be `unique(A)`, so `mutate(A = factor(A, unique(A)))` should do the trick. For the bold text, use the `axis.text.x` element in `theme`:

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(MLE:CS) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), as.factor)) %>%
  mutate(A = factor(A, levels = unique(A))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = R, y = value, group=name, col=name)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1.2) +
  geom_point(size=2.5) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Mean Square Errors") +
  scale_color_grey() + 
  theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(~A, nrow=1, strip.position="bottom") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, face = 'bold'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just a small modification. Is it possible to remove the "name" above the legend on the right? I would like to change that field to something else

Comment: Add `+ labs(color = 'newlabel')` to your plot

Answer (score 2):

A second option would be to use a custom `labeller` function to add the prefix to the strip text. For the axis text you could use `theme` option `axis.text.x`:

```
prepender <- function(x, prefix = "m=") paste0(prefix, x)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(MLE:CS) %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character), as.factor)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = R, y = value, group = name, col = name)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1.2) +
  geom_point(size = 2.5) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Mean Square Errors") +
  scale_color_grey() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold")) +
  facet_wrap(~A, nrow = 1, strip.position = "bottom", labeller = as_labeller(prepender))
```

[image]